# dynamic configure smtp send mail in yii

Tags: php, yii, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using SMTP PHPMailer Extensions in Yii on http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/smtp-mail/ and have sent mail successfully by creating a function sentMail in Controller from it. But overall it require me to config in main/config.php like this:

```
'Smtpmail'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
        'Host'=>"smtp.gmail.com",
        'Username'=>'your@gmail.com',
        'Password'=>'password here',
        'Mailer'=>'smtp',
        'Port'=>587,
        'SMTPAuth'=>true,
        'SMTPSecure' => 'tls',
    ),
```

How can i get all configuration from database to setting SMTP? I have tried to write into function init() and _constructor() of it, but it's not work. And I even config function mailSend in Controller like this:

```
public function mailsend($to, $from = '', $from_name, $subject, $message, $cc = array(), $attachment = array()) {
    $mail = Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
    $mail->Host = Smtpconfig::model()->findByPk(1)->host;
    $mail->Username = Smtpconfig::model()->findByPk(1)->username;
    $mail->Password = Smtpconfig::model()->findByPk(1)->matkhau;
    $mail->IsSMTP = true;
    $mail->Port = Smtpconfig::model()->findByPk(1)->port;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = Smtpconfig::model()->findByPk(1)->phuongthuc;
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->AddAddress($to, "");
    $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

    // Add CC
    if (!empty($cc)) {
        foreach ($cc as $email) {
            $mail->AddCC($email);
        }
    }

    // Add Attchments
    if (!empty($attachment)) {
        foreach ($attachment as $attach) {
            $mail->AddAttachment($attach);
        }
    }

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        return false; // Fail echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return true; // Success
    }
}
```

But not work, either. (Smtpconfig is the name of model include admin smtp mail info)

Comment: Have a look at the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP). It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: can you help me more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is your problem: `$mail->IsSMTP = true`. `IsSMTP` is a method and you're assigning a value to it. The name is misleading, for it actually instructs mailer to use smtp. Try `$mail->IsSMTP()` or `$mail->Mailer = 'smtp'`. Otherwise I think you're on the right track.